# Как упростить разложение по формуле Маклорена?

Tags: ряды

При разложении функции In(1 + sin(x)) можно заменить sin(x) на t, отдельно разложить sin(x), потом всё собрать вместе и получится вот это:
In(1 + sin(x)) = (x - x^3/3! + o(x^4)) - ((x - x^3/3! + o(x^4))^2 / 2) +  ((x - x^3/3! + o(x^4))^3 / 3) + o(x^3) Как это упростить до : x - x^3/3! - x^2/2 + x^3/3 + o(x^3)?

Comment: Раскрыть скобки и сгруппировать все степени, чтоб посчитать суммарные коэффициенты для каждой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас же вот такая формула должна получиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

считается ли это упрощением, которое нужно вам?